# Contact Form 7 - only show for logged in users

Tags: wordpress

I have a contact form 7 form with WordPress.

How can I only show the form to users who are logged in?

If they are logged out - they should go to the login screen, or have it display a login screen.

Answer (score -1):

**Is this what you look for?**

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Your form code here
} else {
    wp_redirect( 'YOUR_LOGIN_URL' );
}
?>
```

Comment: HI,
where would this be added?

Comment: The question does not ask to redirect after successful login, just to show the form. Even though I guess its very hard for 0 coding skills to just add the redirect line after the successful login